# Link pages to sections of a page in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to make my pages link to home page as its section.I am using Angular 8. I just add other pages in home as 'app-features> /app-features>'. But It is not what I want. I want to link the features page to home page in exact way.
I want the codes for it.

Comment: can you add some code pls

Comment: @bubbles I do not know code for that. That is why I asked friend.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what you want ! From your component `app-feature` for instance you want to access to your home page (which is another component `app-home`) ?

Comment: I just want to load features in a section of the home page.That means, when I clicked the features button it should show a section of the home page itself